# jQuery scrolling image video: ProgressiveImageSequence doesn't work

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I'm trying to use this http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-interactive-street-view-jquery tutorial to create an intro for one of our customers. But unfortunately it doesn't work. What is wrong, i've checked very link/path. I copied the hole class again, but i cannot find the mistake.

Did everyone just see where the mistake is: http://www.hausheerag.ch/kunden/habegger/test2.html

thanks for your help.

best regards
thomas

Comment: Sorry, my problem is the the script doesn't work. if you got to the test page you'll see that something its wrong. Unfortunately i don't see what it could be so i though maybe an other eye could see it immediate (i'm sitting since a few hours so my eyes are tired…)

Answer (score 1):

When you download the demo, the line:

```
var imageSeqLoader = new ProgressiveImageSequence( "../shared/street/vid-{index}.jpg"
```

Gets interpreted *wrongly* by your browser upon downloading the source file. So I had to manually change it. (it saves it as `vid-%7bindex%7d.html` instead of `vid-{index}.jpg`)

Also, note that you need to store *all the images of the animation* (otherwise you can't reproduce the animation). Because I want to be sure that it works, I have done all this for you and prepared a package which I've thoroughly tested offline as well as online. **It fully works now!**

See the following working demo:

## [> DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qu4ntyl/stkxysw7/)

Note that I've had to change a little bit of the code to make the demo work on jsFiddle! This because I had to download the images externally from *imgur.com*. Of course, it's much better to host the images on your own server and preload them before starting the animation. Therefore, I've also prepared an offline `.zip` folder with the original *working* source code. You should use that instead!

## [> DOWNLOAD .ZIP](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=28488833464456427177&t=2848883346445642717728750)

Simple run the `tutorial\4\index.html` in your browser and it should work perfectly. Good luck!

Here's a preview of the working example in jsFiddle:

[image]

You can find the website with the original demo here: http://360langstrasse.srf.ch/page/

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is the i've copied from the demo-site! I've now change the loading to the head sector but it doesn't work either..

Comment: yes, i've just checked it again. And tried on FF and Safari, same problem.

Comment: Just have another questions, sorry;-) For my demo page the hole animation should not be fullscreen. it should work on a div of 1280x720px. And there should be 2 buttons for scrolling forward and backwards. do you know how i can do that? Unfortunately I'm a little delayed - if you have time, let me know (of course i can pay for it as well..)

Comment: @StillerEugen First of all, consider accepting my answer. Second of all, I can do this indeed (it's some rather basic jQuery). I first need to finish one of my own projects tonight. If I have time I will post another comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working a lot over the past couple weeks with these files and if your using the latest jquery you might also want to use jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js which can be found at the jquery website. Might help.

Though the tutorial is just to get you started you will need to dive deeper into the code to get it working on touch devices. Also my site that uses ProgressiveImageSequence  is still breaking in chrome. Any thoughts on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954879/progressiveimagesequence-breaks-in-chrome-jquery-jpg-sequence-scroll-and-scrub) is a support ticket.

Anyway, below is the jquery migrate code if you can't find the download. Just copy the javascript file and attach it at the end of your document

```
/*! jQuery Migrate v1.2.1 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
jQuery.migrateMute===void 0&&(jQuery.migrateMute=!0),function(e,t,n){function r(n){var r=t.console;i[n]||(i[n]=!0,e.migrateWarnings.push(n),r&&r.warn&&!e.migrateMute&&(r.warn("JQMIGRATE: "+n),e.migrateTrace&&r.trace&&r.trace()))}function a(t,a,i,o){if(Object.defineProperty)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,a,{configurable:!0,enumerable:!0,get:function(){return r(o),i},set:function(e){r(o),i=e}}),n}catch(s){}e._definePropertyBroken=!0,t[a]=i}var i={};e.migrateWarnings=[],!e.migrateMute&&t.console&&t.console.log&&t.console.log("JQMIGRATE: Logging is active"),e.migrateTrace===n&&(e.migrateTrace=!0),e.migrateReset=function(){i={},e.migrateWarnings.length=0},"BackCompat"===document.compatMode&&r("jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode");var o=e("<input/>",{size:1}).attr("size")&&e.attrFn,s=e.attr,u=e.attrHooks.value&&e.attrHooks.value.get||function(){return null},c=e.attrHooks.value&&e.attrHooks.value.set||function(){return n},l=/^(?:input|button)$/i,d=/^[238]$/,p=/^(?:autofocus|autoplay|async|checked|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped|selected)$/i,f=/^(?:checked|selected)$/i;a(e,"attrFn",o||{},"jQuery.attrFn is deprecated"),e.attr=function(t,a,i,u){var c=a.toLowerCase(),g=t&&t.nodeType;return u&&(4>s.length&&r("jQuery.fn.attr( props, pass ) is deprecated"),t&&!d.test(g)&&(o?a in o:e.isFunction(e.fn[a])))?e(t)[a](i):("type"===a&&i!==n&&l.test(t.nodeName)&&t.parentNode&&r("Can't change the 'type' of an input or button in IE 6/7/8"),!e.attrHooks[c]&&p.test(c)&&(e.attrHooks[c]={get:function(t,r){var a,i=e.prop(t,r);return i===!0||"boolean"!=typeof i&&(a=t.getAttributeNode(r))&&a.nodeValue!==!1?r.toLowerCase():n},set:function(t,n,r){var a;return n===!1?e.removeAttr(t,r):(a=e.propFix[r]||r,a in t&&(t[a]=!0),t.setAttribute(r,r.toLowerCase())),r}},f.test(c)&&r("jQuery.fn.attr('"+c+"') may use property instead of attribute")),s.call(e,t,a,i))},e.attrHooks.value={get:function(e,t){var n=(e.nodeName||"").toLowerCase();return"button"===n?u.apply(this,arguments):("input"!==n&&"option"!==n&&r("jQuery.fn.attr('value') no longer gets properties"),t in e?e.value:null)},set:function(e,t){var a=(e.nodeName||"").toLowerCase();return"button"===a?c.apply(this,arguments):("input"!==a&&"option"!==a&&r("jQuery.fn.attr('value', val) no longer sets properties"),e.value=t,n)}};var g,h,v=e.fn.init,m=e.parseJSON,y=/^([^<]*)(<[\w\W]+>)([^>]*)$/;e.fn.init=function(t,n,a){var i;return t&&"string"==typeof t&&!e.isPlainObject(n)&&(i=y.exec(e.trim(t)))&&i[0]&&("<"!==t.charAt(0)&&r("$(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character"),i[3]&&r("$(html) HTML text after last tag is ignored"),"#"===i[0].charAt(0)&&(r("HTML string cannot start with a '#' character"),e.error("JQMIGRATE: Invalid selector string (XSS)")),n&&n.context&&(n=n.context),e.parseHTML)?v.call(this,e.parseHTML(i[2],n,!0),n,a):v.apply(this,arguments)},e.fn.init.prototype=e.fn,e.parseJSON=function(e){return e||null===e?m.apply(this,arguments):(r("jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string"),null)},e.uaMatch=function(e){e=e.toLowerCase();var t=/(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e)||/(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e)||/(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e)||/(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec(e)||0>e.indexOf("compatible")&&/(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec(e)||[];return{browser:t[1]||"",version:t[2]||"0"}},e.browser||(g=e.uaMatch(navigator.userAgent),h={},g.browser&&(h[g.browser]=!0,h.version=g.version),h.chrome?h.webkit=!0:h.webkit&&(h.safari=!0),e.browser=h),a(e,"browser",e.browser,"jQuery.browser is deprecated"),e.sub=function(){function t(e,n){return new t.fn.init(e,n)}e.extend(!0,t,this),t.superclass=this,t.fn=t.prototype=this(),t.fn.constructor=t,t.sub=this.sub,t.fn.init=function(r,a){return a&&a instanceof e&&!(a instanceof t)&&(a=t(a)),e.fn.init.call(this,r,a,n)},t.fn.init.prototype=t.fn;var n=t(document);return r("jQuery.sub() is deprecated"),t},e.ajaxSetup({converters:{"text json":e.parseJSON}});var b=e.fn.data;e.fn.data=function(t){var a,i,o=this[0];return!o||"events"!==t||1!==arguments.length||(a=e.data(o,t),i=e._data(o,t),a!==n&&a!==i||i===n)?b.apply(this,arguments):(r("Use of jQuery.fn.data('events') is deprecated"),i)};var j=/\/(java|ecma)script/i,w=e.fn.andSelf||e.fn.addBack;e.fn.andSelf=function(){return r("jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack()"),w.apply(this,arguments)},e.clean||(e.clean=function(t,a,i,o){a=a||document,a=!a.nodeType&&a[0]||a,a=a.ownerDocument||a,r("jQuery.clean() is deprecated");var s,u,c,l,d=[];if(e.merge(d,e.buildFragment(t,a).childNodes),i)for(c=function(e){return!e.type||j.test(e.type)?o?o.push(e.parentNode?e.parentNode.removeChild(e):e):i.appendChild(e):n},s=0;null!=(u=d[s]);s++)e.nodeName(u,"script")&&c(u)||(i.appendChild(u),u.getElementsByTagName!==n&&(l=e.grep(e.merge([],u.getElementsByTagName("script")),c),d.splice.apply(d,[s+1,0].concat(l)),s+=l.length));return d});var Q=e.event.add,x=e.event.remove,k=e.event.trigger,N=e.fn.toggle,T=e.fn.live,M=e.fn.die,S="ajaxStart|ajaxStop|ajaxSend|ajaxComplete|ajaxError|ajaxSuccess",C=RegExp("\\b(?:"+S+")\\b"),H=/(?:^|\s)hover(\.\S+|)\b/,A=function(t){return"string"!=typeof t||e.event.special.hover?t:(H.test(t)&&r("'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'"),t&&t.replace(H,"mouseenter$1 mouseleave$1"))};e.event.props&&"attrChange"!==e.event.props[0]&&e.event.props.unshift("attrChange","attrName","relatedNode","srcElement"),e.event.dispatch&&a(e.event,"handle",e.event.dispatch,"jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated"),e.event.add=function(e,t,n,a,i){e!==document&&C.test(t)&&r("AJAX events should be attached to document: "+t),Q.call(this,e,A(t||""),n,a,i)},e.event.remove=function(e,t,n,r,a){x.call(this,e,A(t)||"",n,r,a)},e.fn.error=function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);return r("jQuery.fn.error() is deprecated"),e.splice(0,0,"error"),arguments.length?this.bind.apply(this,e):(this.triggerHandler.apply(this,e),this)},e.fn.toggle=function(t,n){if(!e.isFunction(t)||!e.isFunction(n))return N.apply(this,arguments);r("jQuery.fn.toggle(handler, handler...) is deprecated");var a=arguments,i=t.guid||e.guid++,o=0,s=function(n){var r=(e._data(this,"lastToggle"+t.guid)||0)%o;return e._data(this,"lastToggle"+t.guid,r+1),n.preventDefault(),a[r].apply(this,arguments)||!1};for(s.guid=i;a.length>o;)a[o++].guid=i;return this.click(s)},e.fn.live=function(t,n,a){return r("jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated"),T?T.apply(this,arguments):(e(this.context).on(t,this.selector,n,a),this)},e.fn.die=function(t,n){return r("jQuery.fn.die() is deprecated"),M?M.apply(this,arguments):(e(this.context).off(t,this.selector||"**",n),this)},e.event.trigger=function(e,t,n,a){return n||C.test(e)||r("Global events are undocumented and deprecated"),k.call(this,e,t,n||document,a)},e.each(S.split("|"),function(t,n){e.event.special[n]={setup:function(){var t=this;return t!==document&&(e.event.add(document,n+"."+e.guid,function(){e.event.trigger(n,null,t,!0)}),e._data(this,n,e.guid++)),!1},teardown:function(){return this!==document&&e.event.remove(document,n+"."+e._data(this,n)),!1}}})}(jQuery,window);
```